# Problems with the page layout

Tags: flutter-layout

I need to achieve, using flutter, a layout like the following but I am not capable of it. I have worked with the expanded and the Column MainAxisAlignment but can't solve.
I attach images of the layout I want to achieve:

[image: Only one card displayed]

[image: Three cards displayed]

I am also attaching the code (without padding):

```
Expanded(
   child: Container(
   color: Colors.red,
   child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
         // Row "Chat salvate"
         // Fist card
         // Second card
         // Third card
      ]),
   ),
),
// Button
```

[image: What do I have now]

Comment: What is the problem you are facing?

Comment: I want the button to always be at the bottom and that when there are three cards the padding is the same among all widgets (represented by the blue lines in the photos).
When there are one or two cards, however, I want them to hold the top position

Comment: Can you share a code snippet?

Answer (score 1):

I have created an example UI in DartPad with the same design you are trying to implement.

Check it out [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=e3b339f195bb6115a53d5761d863a7ca).

Comment: Thank you so much even if it's not exactly what I was looking for

Comment: You are always welcome, if it answered your question, then please accept the answer with the check mark under the vote.